# How to remove transparency in the drop down menu in nav bar so it does not show the page text behind it only using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding and my university has presented us with an assignment, and I need help removing the `transparency` from the `drop-down menu`. When you scroll down you can see the body of the page behind the `navbar`. `No opacity` is set. Also when I scroll down with the transparent nav bar the cursor fails to go past where the text of the body begins.

Thank you for any help!

I have attached a code snippet for both CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.html logo {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.font-element {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The &#60;b&#62; Element </title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img class="html logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="HTML&#38;CSS"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a>HTML 5</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="belement.html">&#60;b&#62; Element</a></li>
            <li><a href="element2.html">Element 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="element3.html">Element 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="element4.html">Element 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="element5.html">Element 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="element6.html">Element 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="element7.html">Element 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="element8.html">Element 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="element9.html">Element 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="element10.html">Element 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>CSS</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="css1.html">CSS 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="css2.html">CSS 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="css3.html">CSS 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <h1>The &#60;<span class="font-element">b</span>&#62; Element</h1>
  <p>The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key words in a document abstract, product names
    in a review, actionable words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede.
    <h2>Example Code:</h2>
    This is some &#60;b&#62;really bold text &#60;&#47;b&#62;.
    <h2>The result:</h2>
    This is some <b>really bold text</b>.
    <p>You can find more information on the official W3C specification by clicking here.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment on these two lines on your CSS file

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
/*   height: auto; */
/*   background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211); */
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the text is over the dropdown and as per your code you want,

```
ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

`li` to be `hovered` to show the other li. Now, because the text is over the dropdown when you move your cursor down the cursor is hovering on the text, and that is why it disappears.

---

**Solution:**

#### Bring the dropdown above the text.

Add `z-index` to the `ul`. Also, add `position` of `relative`.

```
ul {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /* ↓↓ below ones ↓↓ */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Check it in action on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ZEBRmQr?editors=1100).

Comment: thank you very much that's exactly what I need. I appreciate you.